# Can this kind of dependency injection be achieved with NestJS?

Tags: dependency-injection, decorator, nestjs

I want to inject the result of a Nest service method as dependency in a short way. Example is a logging facility, where a child logger is derived from the main logger with a new prefix.

It should be something like this (long version):

```js
@Injectable()
class MyService {
  private logger;

  constructor(private loggerService: LoggerService) {
    this.logger = loggerService.getChildLogger('prefix');
  }

  someMethod() {
    this.logger.info('Hello');
  }  
}
```

But in a short version, something like this - maybe with a decorator:

```js
@Injectable()
class MyService {
  constructor(@logger('prefix') logger: LoggerService) {
  }

  someMethod() {
    this.logger.info('Hello');
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create providers for your loggers using factories injecting your `LoggerService` :

The `LoggerService`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class LoggerService {
  getChildLogger(scope: string) {
    return new Logger(scope);
  }
}
```

The `MyService`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(@Inject('MY_SERVICE_LOGGER_TOKEN') public childLogger) {}

  onModuleInit() {
    this.childLogger.log('Hello World');
  }
}
```

The module:

```js
@Module({
  providers: [
    LoggerService,
    MyService,
    {
      provide: 'MY_SERVICE_LOGGER_TOKEN', 
      useFactory: (loggerService) => loggerService.getChildLogger('scope'), 
      inject: [LoggerService]
    },
  ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Comment: I just wanted to have the scope set per Service/Class and not per Module. But thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a solution provided by Livio Brunner:
https://github.com/BrunnerLivio/nestjs-logger-decorator

Comment: this link goes to 404 github error page